# How to test InterruptedException

Tags: java

I have the following method which works fine. I am trying to test the scenario where an InterruptedException is thrown. This is how I am testing currently which works if I only run this single test. But if I were to run all remaining 5 tests in my test class, some starts failing. All tests passes when I run them individually thus clearly my Thread interrupt in the test is affecting other tests. How can I write my test in a way it won't affect other tests?

```
@Component
class A{
    @Autowired
    private Helper helper;

    private static ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

    // static variable in class
    private final Future<String> number = executor.submit(() -> helper.method());

    //method to be tested 
    public String getNumber() {
        try {
            return this.number.get();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            throw new CustomException1();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            throw new CustomException2();
        }
    }
}

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
clas ATest{

    @InjectMocks
    private A a;

    @Mock
    private Helper helper;

    // this is my test method which passes when ran individually. But will affect other tests if everything is ran same time. 
    @Test
    public void testMethod() {

        when(helper.method()).thenReturn("222");
        String num = a.getNumber();

        // doing this on purpose so I would land inside the catch. This line is causing issues.
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();

        try {
            assertEquals("222", num);
        }catch (CustomException1 e){
            // I will land here for this test as expected
            // do some assertions
        }

        // Thread.currentThread().interrupt(); // Tried calling it again here to clear the flag but doesn't work. 
    }

    // another few tests ..... 
}
```

Comment: The status can be cleared by using `Thread.interrupted()` method. `Thread.currentThread().interrupt();` sets the flag - it does not clear it. However I would advise to rethink the design and make your ThreadPool injectable and further seperate the task from the executor of this task.

Comment: Being interrupted means almost nothing until someone actually checks if the thread is interrupted - and as a rule of thumb, those are the ones throwing `InterruptedException`. So you should show the other test, which are affected.

Comment: Something doesn't add up about this. The interrupted status is visible only to the the current thread. Even if tests run in parallel, the interrupted status of one thread wouldn't impact tests running in other threads. As written (with the second `interrupt()` commented out), the interrupted status is clear when this test exits. I suspect the problem would only occur when that second `interrupt()` call (after the subject is tested) is uncommented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way to do that is to Mock the interrupted exception

```
when(helper.method())).thenThrow(InterruptedException.class);
```

But you can also just clear the interruption flag by calling the method:

```
Thread.interrupted()
```

Comment: The first solution here is not right. Mockito will not allow to throw a checked exception. Executing this will result in :


org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: 
Checked exception is invalid for this method!
Invalid: java.lang.InterruptedException

Answer (score 0):

You should simulate that your `Future` returns `InterruptedException`

Try this

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ATest {

@Test(expected = CustomException1.class)
public void testMethod() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
    Future future = mock(Future.class);
    when(future.get()).thenThrow(new InterruptedException());
    A a = new A(future);

    a.getNumber();
}

// another few tests .....
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Given that the accepted answer throws an Exception when used, as Radioactive pointed it out, I thought I'd share a workaround to test this using Mockito, which makes use of the `willAnswer()` method. It would look something like this:

```
import static org.mockito.BDDMockito.given;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension;

@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class Test {
    @Test
    void test() {    
        given(helper.method()).willAnswer(invocation -> {
            throw new InterruptedException();
        });
        ...
    }
}
```